# can ansible use for physical server provisioning?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there any way to provision servers (install os in physical servers ) using Ansible.

I couldnt find any proper article on this from internet. Please help if you have some experience on it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. For example:

- PXE boot an image with preinstalled Ansible
- Run [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html#ansible-pull)

Comment: could you please give some more information on how to configure this. I am first time using ansible for infra provisiong :)